# Open file as a buffer in Python?

Tags: python, pyhdf

I have a compressed HDF file (HDF.Z) and would like to open it like that:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
f = Popen(['zcat', 'myfile.HDF.Z'], stdout=PIPE).stdout
```

In order to get the data I need to use pyhdf:

```
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC
mydata = SD(f, SDC.READ)
```

However, this results in an error message:

```
*** TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Is there a way to open this file as a buffer to read it in? Btw: what is a buffer?

Comment: Shouldn't `'myfile.hdf'` be `'myfile.hdf.z'`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 yes I changed that in the question.

Comment: @perreal how do I give it the content of the file?

Comment: @perreal No. It [wants the file name](http://pysclint.sourceforge.net/pyhdf/pyhdf.SD.html#SD).

Comment: Since the file is extracted via zcat and opened with Popen I only have the stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a short glance, I found no way to make it access an open stream.

You can do the following:

- Create a temporary file where you unpack the file.
- Give the name of this temporary file to `SD()`.

Another option is very system dependent: you could take the file handle and do

```
SD('/dev/fd/%d' % f.fileno(), SDC.READ)
```

bit this is very platform-dependent (Linux only) and, if `SD()` does `mmap()` by any chance, it will fail.

Comment: The temporary unpacking of the file works, although this takes more time (considering the fact that I perform this action on hundreds of files).